# can we add a Header to UIList to show up on top of the UI component?

Tags: interface

i am wondering if this is possible, as i can´t find any topic in that matter.

Or maybe the option is to create a fake content for the row index 0 and start adding property´s content at row 1... what do you think ? any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

i don't know whether this is what you want, but if you use the template "ui list simple" and you add this:

```
 row = layout.row()
 layout.label(text="Header:")
```

you will get:

[image]